# controlling codeigniter pagination url

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pagination

First, i need to explain you what am i doing :

**Note** : This project is using `codeigniter` framework

I have a `view` for the header and the tabs :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Backend-Vihara Dharma Bhakti</title>
<link href="../../../style/style_backend.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>style/style_backend.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });

  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>

<div id="header"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="backend/umat">Daftar Umat</a></li>
            <li><a href="backend/pengurus">Daftar Pengurus</a></li>
            <li><a href="backend/absensi">Absensi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</head>
```

Notice that i use the tabs to load **different** content(`controller`) **below** the header and tabs.

And the `controller` for the header and the tabs :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Backend_home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('template/header_v');
    }
}
```

Then, i have another `view` to show the content (i will use the first link(`backend/umat`) for the example)

```
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
     </script>

    <div id="form_search">
        <?php echo form_open('backend/index') ?>
            <!--<p>
                <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_search', $data_search, 'id="ddl_search"');?>
            </p>-->
            <p>
                Kelas :
                <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_kelas1', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas1"');?> -
                <?php echo form_dropdown('ddl_kelas2', $list_kelas, 'id="ddl_kelas2"');?>
            </p>
            <p>
                Nama : <?php echo form_input('txt_nama');?>
                Alamat : <?php echo form_input('txt_alamat');?>
                Tanggal Lahir : <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
            </p>
                <?php echo form_submit('btn_search', 'Search');?>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php echo $table ?>
        <?php echo $pagination ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And its `controller` :

```
public function umat() {
        //check authorization
        if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
            redirect('backend');

        //pagination
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('/backend/umat/');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->backend_m->count_umat();
        $config['per_page'] = 10; 
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        //table     
        $data_umat = $this->backend_m->get_umat();

        $this->table->set_heading(
            'No',
            'Nama',
            'Kelas',
            'Alamat',
            'Sekolah',
            'Nomor Telepon',
            'Keterangan'        
        );

        $no = 1;
        foreach($data_umat as $list_temp) 
        {
            $this->table->add_row(
                $no++,
                $list_temp->nama,
                $list_temp->kelas,
                $list_temp->alamat,
                $list_temp->sekolah,
                $list_temp->no_tlpn,
                $list_temp->keterangan
            );
        }


        //masukkan data dari DB ke DDL
        $data_kelas = $this->backend_m->get_kelas();

        $data['list_kelas'][0] = 'Pilih Kelas';

        foreach($data_kelas as $row)
        {
            $data['list_kelas'][$row->kelas_id] = $row->kelas;
        }

        /*$data_search = array('kelas' => 'Kelas', 
                             'nama' => 'Nama',
                             'alamat' => 'Alamat',
                             'bulan' => 'Bulan Lahir');*/

        $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();

        $this->load->view('backend/umat_v', $data);
    }
```

Note that i use pagination in this controller.

**Main Problem**

Because i use 2 different `view`(html) in my page, the `url` will follow the header(tabs) one.
Its `url` is `http://localhost/ci_gabdb/index.php/backend_home`

Everything works fine until i click the second page of my pagination's index. The `url` will **change** to `http://localhost/ci_gabdb/index.php/backend/umat/10` and it makes my page **lost** its css and header(tabs).

*Screen shoot*

**Before** i click any pagination (the pagination index is below, i dont include it so you can see the header and tabs) : (`http://localhost/ci_gabdb/index.php/backend_home`)

[image]

**After** i click the second page of my pagination's index : (`http://localhost/ci_gabdb/index.php/backend/umat/10`)

[image]

Sorry for the long post :D Please kindly help me if you have any solution to this problem, i dont mind to change my code **a lot**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rethink how you're doing your templates. I use templates too, what you need to do is pass the view to the template.

Basic example.

Template page:

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('content',$main_content);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Then in your controllers for each page you do this:

```
$data['main_content'] = 'umat';
$this->load->view('template',$data);
```

So essentially what you're going to do is EVERY page you load is going to load the template file, the specific page is going to pass to the correct place in that template via $data.

This way you don't have to try and pass multiple views from every controller function and you don't have to worry about things like the issue you have now where pagination requires a single url.

If I'm understanding your issue correctly reworking your pages to load like this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Sir you helped me in another question too. Okay i will try it now

Comment: I use this in my controller(not main) : 

$data['page'] = 'umat';
$this->load->view('header_v', $data);

And this in my view's (header_v) controller :

$this->load->view('template/header_v');
$this->load->view('backend/'.$page);

But i got an error :  Undefined variable: page. I got confuse about passing the variable to the controller of the header_v

Comment: If you're already using a template of some sort then your pagination URL should be calling the function that loads that page, sorry I'm a little lost on your structure to be honest. If umat is already loading the header then how are you managing to lose the header on pagination? O.o

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, i will just use the 'require' for now. Thanks for your help :D